# How do I avoid prevent the removal of tags in PHP Tidy?

Tags: php, html, htmltidy

I'm using Tidy to produce clean output, but it somehow removes my `<nav>` tags. Are there any configuration options that will avoid this?

Comment: can you post your expected / actual output and your code ?

Comment: fix the html so your tags aren't broken?

Comment: Code: [link](https://gist.github.com/6da6fa787958e7838c07) Output: [link](https://gist.github.com/c5a6e6953168207ed369)

Comment: If the link ain't working just remove the '.git'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying tidy library doesn't know anything about HTML5.

There is a new project underway to make a new tidy that handles HTML5: https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5  That's not going to help you here, though.